# I can't import data from csv file on SQL PgAdmin4

Tags: sql, csv, import, pgadmin-4

When I try to import it, this error message shows up:

"ERREUR:  syntaxe en entrée invalide pour le type integer : « 0;Iron Maiden;1975;United Kingdom;New wave of british heavy »
CONTEXTE : COPY metal, ligne 1, colonne id : « 0;Iron Maiden;1975;United Kingdom;New wave of british heavy »

I set up the columns like id - integer, band_name - text, formed - numeric, origin - text, style - text. I even tried to switch on/off the Header option, but I had no success. Also, I changed the id type from integer to numeric, but to no avail.
Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually there's no code to be shared. I'm using the PgAdmin4 GUI to try to import a csv file like 0;Iron Maiden;1975;United Kingdom;New wave of british heavy. I've already created the table, added the columns description on PGAdmin4 GUI like id - integer, band_name - text, formed - numeric, origin - text, style - text, but the popped up error is "ERREUR: syntaxe en entrée invalide pour le type integer : « 0;Iron Maiden;1975;United Kingdom;New wave of british heavy » CONTEXTE : COPY metal, ligne 1, colonne id : « 0;Iron Maiden;1975;United Kingdom;New wave of british heavy ».